# IdentityServer3 returns invalid_scope for authorize endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3, nopcommerce

I have and IdentityServer3 installed on my ASP.NET MVC website and a client (a NopCommerce plugin) defined as below (urls are just for test):

```
new Client
                   {
                       ClientName    = "Deep Stores",
                       ClientId      = "deepstores",
                       ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                                       {
                                           new Secret("0B0A3FD3-F30C-428C-B1A3-6E570103614D".Sha256())
                                       },
                       AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
                       RedirectUris    = new List<string>
                                         {
                                             "http://localhost:2030/plugins/ExternalAuthDeepStudies/logincallback"
                                         },
                       Flow                   = Flows.AuthorizationCode,
                       AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
                       AllowedScopes          = StandardScopes.All.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
                   }
```

When trying to get authorization token with a url like below, It works for the first time (login appears and grant page blah blah) but for the rest of requests it returns `error=invalid_scope` for my callback!

request to authorize endpoint :

```
https://127.0.0.1/core/connect/authorize?client_id=deepstores&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2030%2Fplugins%2FExternalAuthDeepStudies%2Flogincallback&scope=profile&response_type=code
```

what happens? and why do i get this error?

scopes are defined as :

```
public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
    {
        return new[]
               {
                   StandardScopes.OpenId,
                   StandardScopes.Profile,
                   StandardScopes.Email,
                   StandardScopes.Address,
                   StandardScopes.Phone,
                   StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                   StandardScopes.RolesAlwaysInclude,
                   StandardScopes.AllClaims,

               };
    }
```

Note that I use EntityFramework and all my staff are stored in database. plus that I use ASP.NET Identity for managing users and roles.

Comment: *a NopCommerce plugin* could you let us know, which plugin?

Comment: a custom external authentication plugin, is being developed by myself.

Comment: Can't create a plugin from start, would be good to share plugin source code anywhere if possible!